# When would you use the new dynamic GORM methods findOrSaveBy/Where?

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I am experimenting with Grails 2.0.1 and have read through the documentation but am confused by the new dynamic methods:

```
def book = Book.findOrSaveWhere(author: 'Daniel Suarez', title: 'Daemon')
def book = Book.findOrSaveByAuthorAndTitle('Daniel Suarez', 'Daemon')
```

I can imagine some situations where `findOrCreateBy/Where` might come in handy but for the life of me I can't think of any situations where `findOrSaveBy/Where` would be called for.  Even in the [test case on github](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.0.x/grails-test-suite-persistence/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/orm/hibernate/FindOrSaveByPersistenceMethodTests.groovy) the motivation for this method isn't obvious to me.  It seems like in each test case either you clearly want to `find` or clearly want to `save` so having a `findOrSave` just makes the intent of the code less clear.

[The original JIRA entry](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7395) for these features doesn't discuss the motivation or give any background.  Could someone please give me some scenarios where these methods would be beneficial?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findOrCreateWhere` - User.findOrCreateWhere(login: ‘bala’), this will find a user in the database with login as bala. If it does not find one it will create a new object but will not save it. You have to save it explicitly.

`findOrSaveWhere` - User.findOrSaveWhere(login: ‘bala’), this will find a user in the database with login as bala. If it does not find one it will create a new object and also will save that.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I must have read that section five times in the documentation and for some reason it just didn't click.  That makes sense, thanks for the info.

Comment: Can I `findOrSaveByField()` with additional attributes that should be saved with? i.e Can I find by ID, if no match, save with, name, email, city etc?

Comment: @Pila did you figure out?

Comment: No @Dracarys. I had to make a query, followed by a condition. If the query returns some results, then I do not save a new instance, else, create a new instance with your attributes.